# How do I check the space usage of a github project owned by me?

Tags: github

It is said that Github only allows one project to use 100Gb data.

How do I check how much space my project has used?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a personal account you can access repository under settings.  Here: https://github.com/settings/repositories

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can review the space used by individual repos at https://github.com/settings/repositories.

To check the storage space for other space-limited Github features such as Actions/Packages/Codespaces/LFS data [go to the billing section.](https://github.com/settings/billing) Once there, find the 'Usage this month' section that's down near the bottom of the page. It will show you the current usage for these other items and how close you are to exceeding your limits.